# How to find cell in table by description (no class or id) and manipulate the content of the next cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

Since jQuery isn't my best skillset I need a little help as I seem to be unable to find a post which I can use as reference for my issue.

Within a table (with `class="shop_attributes"`), I'd like to manipulate the string embedded in the paragraph section within the next cell (`<td>...</td>`) directly after the `<th>Reference ID</th>` cell...

How can I get hold of that string (29909, 40887, 51890, 63388) so I can manipulate it with a text replace function (I want to transform them into URLs)?

Secondly, since I can have multiple lines / cells in the same table with `<th>Reference ID</th>`. How would I be able to process all the possible lines with Reference ID (so both "29909, 40887, 51890, 63388" and "255")?

Below is a very much simplified setup of the table. In reality there will be many more rows (attributes) present within the table.

```
<table class="shop_attributes">             
  <tbody>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>29909, 40887, 51890, 63388</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Attribute X</th>
      <td>
        <p>X</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>255</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you could assign a class to either the `<td>` or the `<p>` which contains the numbers you want to reference, but if this is already set in stone for some reason, you can use the `:contains()` selector to find the Reference ID `<th>` elements, then loop through those grabbing the string from the next cell's `<p>` element:

```
var refCells = $('th:contains("Reference ID")');
refCells.each(function(){
    var string = $(this).next('td').find('p').text();
    console.log(string);
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6cuxesu/

Comment: Yup I know - but the code is being generated by WooCommerce so to get that done I would have to hack into the core of WooCommerce which I prefer not to do ;)
Thanks for your example - never knew there was a :contains method in jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? The demo uses the `:contains()` pseudo-selector and `.html( fn )` to achieve both the selection and manipulation.

```js
$('.shop_attributes th:contains("Reference ID")')
.next('td').find('p').html(function(i,html) {
     return html.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<a href="#$1">$1</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_attributes">             
  <tbody>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>29909, 40887, 51890, 63388</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Attribute X</th>
      <td>
        <p>X</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>255</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>129909, 140887, 151890, 163388</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Attribute X</th>
      <td>
        <p>X</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <td>
        <p>255</p>
      </td>     
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow - thanks a million! A full working solution in only 4 lines!! And I was thinking that this would require much more lines.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.